# WPF XAML How to change background to match the main Windows

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, background

This is a simple question but I cannot find the correct answer to solve this problem.

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="IDSLogUtilityWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Height="385" Width="622" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="White">
    <DockPanel Margin="1" LastChildFill="False">
        <DockPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFDAC7C7" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </DockPanel.Background>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="25">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="MenuItem_FileExit"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Settings">
                <MenuItem Header="CAN Interface" Click="MenuItem_CAN_Interface"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Help">
                <MenuItem Header="About" Click="MenuItem_HelpAbout"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <DockPanel Margin="10" Width="590" Height="80" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" LastChildFill="False">
            <Image Source="images\gateway.bmp" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Stretch="Fill" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" Width="140" Height="60"/>
            <Image Source="images\gateway.bmp" Stretch="None" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,30,0,-50"/>
            <Image Source="images\gateway.bmp" Stretch="None" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0,30,5,-50"/>

        </DockPanel>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

So I have a WPF XAML application in which there is the main window and I want to add several images which backgrounds obviously are not the same as the Window.

[image: Window WPF]

How can I manipulate each image's background to match the Window (in this case the Window background is a lineargradiendbrush but if this is not possible I can use a solid background.

As you can see the look of the images looks pretty ugly.

Thanks and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look into using png images with a transparent background, [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12900988/2557263)

Comment: I had already read that answer but it does nothing. Added Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True" to the Window and converted my image from bmp to png and image still shows with a white background.

Comment: Be sure to edit the resulting png to make the background transparent. Since bmp doesn't support transparency, a straightforward conversion will preserve the white areas. Edit them to be really transparent, then apply the linked solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your .bmp image file itself contains the white background. Try with .png format image.